# Unable to upload APK on google play certificate issues

Tags: android

```html
You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: F2:6B:9A:EB:3B:8D:F8:53:59:C7:D3:7D:1D:BC:60:2A:53:28:7C:95 ]
and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: 82:AC:A8:E7:01:7F:E0:D2:56:DC:8A:98:FB:02:AF:FA:B9:AA:29:4F ]
```

My Previous app is not hybird app.. now i want to replace .. any solution ?
Using same package name

Comment: The certificate for signing has to be the same as previously. You are using a different certificate now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must sign the package with the same key, as the previous .apk was signed. You can't change key between versions, the initial signing key for particular package name is final till the lifespan of app.

If you lost the original key (or if your key did expire ... which will eventually happen to most of the apps in 30-50 years), you have to re-release the application under different package name, and build up the user base again.

See official docs for more details:
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Comment: My previous app is non hybird app now i create hybird app, i don't know how to use this key into hybird app..

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by hybird app (nor hybrid), and I don't see how that should affect signing of .apk.
Study documentation of your build tools, where the signing happens, and what key storage is used. Retrieve the original key-storage from old version, and set it up for new version, so the same key is used to sign the new app. And read the signing docs + google to understand what signing the .apk means.

Comment: Previous app  simply i create using android studio now my updated app is cordova ionic app, don't know how to use previous key on  ionic platform

Comment: So simply find key store in old project, and simply read the ionic platform docs to see where you can put the key store for android apk signing during release build. You simply had to specify the key already, as you have invalid new key in the new project, so you simply probably hit some generate new signing key during that new project setup without understanding what you are doing, and simply without reading any docs about it.